# What does a party for 13 yo look like today?

Tags: teen, party

All stars are aligned for the first teenage party of my 13 yo son, but my last 13 yo party was a long long time ago and I simply do not know what they look like today (for context - I could have been at "[La Boum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHPeoxOciog)", this was the reference for my generation)

The advice I am looking for from the ones who went through that is rather on the organizational side: what they are normally interested in, the kind of food, and general logistics.

This is in a quiet suburb of Paris, I am not worried about the security (as asked in [another question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14769/throwing-parties-for-teenagers)) but rather on what to do so that it is pleasant for everyone (his friends will be there, as well as some friends from abroad). I will be at home (hiding a closet or something) and my son and his friends are definitely on the quiet and cool side.

I will organize this with him, obviously, but since so far the parties have been typical "birthday parties for kids" and not "the kind of party where you dance and there are girls around", I would like to help manage this a bit.

Any advice is welcome (this will be in a flat so no pool parties), I would like him to hopefully remember his truly first one as fondly as I remember mine.

Comment: Hi WoJ - this type of question has been tried before, but the problem is that there are as many different types of party as there are kids. It's just not answerable without a long list - and SE doesn't do list questions. That said, Dan's answer is about as good as you will get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to figure out a party is to ask him what he wants. 
He could want something as simple as pizza, snack foods, movies and a game console, or something a bit more planned as a last hurrah of childhood. Without asking him you have no way of knowing.

At thirteen, I wouldn't worry too much about girls being over and dancing, most boys at that age are still trying to figure out how to get over their embarrassment and will treat the girls as cool friends rather than anything else. So again ask him what he wants and if girls will be over, ask him what the plan is for them.

Comment: +1 Ask him what he wants and give him a little time to figure it out and get back to you. When I was a 13yo boy I had some male friends come over for swimming during the day and play video games all night.

Comment: +1 for find out what he wants. You'd probably see more dancing with the 10 year olds than the 13 year olds.